# How to forbid certain anyOf items in json schema array to occur more than once

Tags: arrays, json, validation, jsonschema

Considering the following json schema:

```json
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "anyOf":[
            { 
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties":false,
                "properties": {
                    "foo":{"type":"string"}
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties":false,
                "properties": {
                    "bar":{"type":"number"}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How could I specify, that the first schema in `anyOf` may come up indefinetly, but the second schema may only come up once?

The json below is supposed to be **valid** because it contains only one element matching the second `anyOf` schema:

```json
[
  {
    "foo":"hello"
  },
  {
    "foo":"world"
  },
  {
    "bar":42
  }
]
```

The json below is supposed to be **invalid** because it contains more than one elements that match the second `anyOf` schema:

```json
[
  {
    "foo":"hello"
  },
  {
    "foo":"world"
  },
  {
    "bar":42
  },
  {
    "bar":24
  }
]
```

I am looking for solutions in any json-schema draft version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In draft 2019-09 and 2020-12, you can use `contains` + `minContains` + `maxContains` to assert that something can appear in the array at most one time.

```json
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "anyOf": [
      { "$ref": "#/$defs/foo-string" },
      { "$ref": "#/$defs/foo-number" }
    ]
  },
  "contains": { "$ref": "#/$defs/foo-string" },
  "minContains": 0,
  "maxContains": 1
}
```

In draft-04 - draft-07, there is no way to express contains-only-one. The best you can do is to require that the thing that can appear only once is always the first item of the array. This says that the first item can be "foo-string" or "foo-number" and all the rest must be "foo-number".

```json
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    {
      "anyOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/$defs/foo-string" },
        { "$ref": "#/$defs/foo-number" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "additionalItems": { "$ref": "#/definitions/foo-number" }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I think I can use the latest draft. Not to drive this too far but do you see a way to adapt this, so several of the anyOf schemas can be limited to one appearance max?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to add additional contains constraints. You can use `allOf` if you need to use the same keyword more than once in a schema. `"allOf": [{ "contains": { ... } }, { "contains": { ... } }]`

Comment: Yes, thats exactly it!