# How to ensure with JSON Schema that a property occurs only once

Tags: jsonschema

I want to ensure that a property occurs only once in a JSON file.  Let's take the simplest possible JSON Schema to illustrate my question:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "singleton": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation is that `singleton` is allowed to occur only once.  However, this file is schema-compliant according to the `check-jsonschema` tool for Python:

```
{
    "singleton": "ok",
    "singleton": "not ok"
}
```

How can I limit in the schema the number of occurrences?  Is there something like `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` in XML Schema?

(Note: there is a [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66358507/how-to-forbid-certain-anyof-items-in-json-schema-array-to-occur-more-than-once) but it is related to arrays, not standalone properties)

Comment: JSONSchema shouldn't need that to be a feature because its a feature [built into JSON itself](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-4): *The names within an object [SHOULD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119) be unique.*

Comment: @Quentin: I agree that the names should be unique, actually I want to _detect_ such duplicates, because I consider them as errors.

Comment: My point is that that check seems *out of scope* for the tool you are using.

Comment: If I understand you right, I have not overlooked anything while reading the [docs](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/index.html); i.e., it is [by design] not possible to do such checks using JSONSchema.  Correct?

Comment: there is no way to limit number of properties. JSON itself, allows duplicate properties.   here's a great run down of the RFC's explanations of this behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23195243/8564731

Comment: @JeremyFiel: Thanks for the explanation. I understand why JSON - as a general-purpose notation - allows duplicates but - even knowing that schemas are not meant (or cannot) perform all checks - IMHO it is a shortcoming that JSONSchema cannot detect duplicates - but then again, it is still in the "draft" stage...

Comment: regardless of the `draft` stage, i'm not sure this has ever been considered by JSON Schema.  you can probably clarify that in the JSON Schema slack with the maintainers. https://json-schema.slack.com

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible - you may have missed a similar [previous stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259902/writing-json-schema-to-detect-objects-with-duplicate-names) question. If schema validators checked for duplicate property keys, I would imagine this would significantly degrade performance as well.

At schemastore, we [use jsonlint](https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/blob/8abbba345b2c58779586a26c8b11d34042cc810b/src/Gruntfile.cjs#L950) to check for duplicate object keys. Conveniently, it prints the column and row numbers where this occurs (iirc the `find-duplicated-property-keys` package does not do this).

Answer (score -2):

I think this schema does the job:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "singleton": {}
    },
    "required": ["singleton"],
    "allOf": [
      {
        "not": {
          "properties": {
            "singleton": { "type": "string" },
            "singleton": { "type": "string" }
          },
          "required": ["singleton", "singleton"]
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

... because it accepts this code

```
  {"singleton": "ok",
  }
```

but it rejects this code

```
 {"singleton": "ok",
  "singleton": "not ok"}
```